# Не работает Collectors.groupingBy()

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть лист `List<Category> categories`, в классе `Category` есть метод `List<Product> getProducts()`, который возвращает лист с продуктами, класс `Product` содержит в себе `categoryName` и `price`, так вот с помощью StreamApi нужно из `categories` создать мапу - `Map<String categoryName, Long sumOfPrices>`, которая содержит названия категорий и сумму цен продуктов в ней.
Но компилятор не дает сгенерировать следующий код

```
categories.stream()
   .map(Category::getProducts)
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getCategory))
```

примерная структура классов

```
public class Category {
   private List<Product> products;

   public List<Product> getProducts() {
      return products;
   }
}
```

```
public class Product {
   private String categoryName;
   private Long price;

   public String getCategoryName() {
      return categoryName;
   }

   public Long getPrice() {
      return price;
   }
}
```

Пример:

```
Products:
prod1(category: Category1, price: 45)
prod2(category: Category1, price: 55)

prod3(category: Category2, price: 45)
```

```
Вывод - Map<String, Long> sums: 
Category1 - 100
Category2 - 45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
categories.stream()
   .map(Category::getProducts)
```

Создает стрим из списков продуктов, а не просто стрим продуктов. Далее нам нужно развернуть стрим списков продуктов в стрим продуктов, а стрим продуктов перевести в мапу из продуктов, сгруппировать по ключу и суммировать по значению.

```
Map<String, Long> collect = categories
        .stream()
        .map(Category::getProducts)
        .flatMap(products -> products.stream().map(product -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(product.getCategory(), product.getPrice())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.summingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```